# Jira Software 7.1.2 - Sprint ID from AO_60DB71_SPRINT does not match the IDs on CustomFieldValue

Tags: sql, oracle, join, foreign-keys, jira

I'm currently on a project where I need to develop some analysis using the Jira Software database. We have Jira 7.1.2, and it is installed on Oracle.

I did some research and found out that the **Sprint ID** from the table **AO_60DB71_RAPIDVIEW** should be found on the table **customfieldvalue** (field **stringvalue**) so that I can **join issues with sprints**.

However, although the IDs I get from customfieldvalue match the ones I get from Jira UI, they **do not** match the ones on AO_60DB71_RAPIDVIEW (hence making it impossible for me to join issues with sprints for my dashboards).

Does anyone know how can I solve that, please?

Also, I know that the sprint is with different IDs on the two tables because I have its name on both of them (fields Name on AO_60DB71_RAPIDVIEW and NewString on customfieldvalue).

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Share sample data info

Comment: Hi Himanshu! Do you need the code I'm running or the results I'm getting?

Comment: I mean some sorta input and expected output as above you have mentioned some id mismatch so whats the table structure and mismatched data sample